# Database INSERT sends event to back-end

Tags: android, mysql, events, service, backend

I have an Android application which pulls information from the internet into a list. I know one of the ways of downloading the new content only is to use an `IntentService`, for example, which would query the `createdOn` attribute of each entry in the table. However, this would probably drain battery especially if I want the list in my app to be `up-to-date every minute`. This would make for a new service launched every minute.

My question is, is there a way for a developer to receive a message (fire an event) from MySQL when an insert was performed, so that only then an intent service is started to download the new content. Are there any other efficient ways?

Thank you!

Comment: mysql can write to a file in its format of csv primarily. It can even path to it. But it is not exactly flexible in the sense of a general purpose programming language. In addition it could use a UDF embedded in the mysql server either dynamically loaded or re-compiled. So that is real hard to pull off for the average guy. So your best bet is the first one. Something on your end would have to be scanning for the files arriving. Like in Java that you program in. That then begs the question why do that, when your java program could just be a mysql programming driving the whole thing anyway.